# How a pixel is represented in the array data inside a FITS file?

Tags: c++, fits

I have a task to read `fits` files and show the image (if present) in one system. This system accepts the image data as an array of pixels that can be either as a single chunk of 8 bits (for grayscale) or as 3 chunks of 8 bits each (for RGB). I'm trying to read the file generated in the tests from the `CCfits` library but for me the data there makes no sense to how it is displayed in all `fits` viewers I've checked.

So this is the code that generates the data array in the sample file I'm using:

```
std::valarray<int> array(nelements);
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; ++i)
{
    array[std::slice(vectorLength*static_cast<int>(i),vectorLength,1)] = row + i;     
}
```

This is the header:

```
SIMPLE  =                    T / file does conform to FITS standard             
BITPIX  =                   16 / number of bits per data pixel                  
NAXIS   =                    2 / number of data axes                            
NAXIS1  =                  300 / length of data axis 1                          
NAXIS2  =                  200 / length of data axis 2                          
EXTEND  =                    T / FITS dataset may contain extensions            
COMMENT   FITS (Flexible Image Transport System) format is defined in 'Astronomy
COMMENT   and Astrophysics', volume 376, page 359; bibcode: 2001A&A...376..359H 
BZERO   =                32768 / offset data range to that of unsigned short    
BSCALE  =                    1 / default scaling factor                         
EXPOSURE=                 1500 / Total Exposure Time                            
OMEGA   =    (-0.5, 0.8660254) /  Complex cube root of 1                        
NEWVALUE=                   42 /  Test of adding keyword to different extension 
STRING  = ' Rope   '           / trailing blank test 1                          
STRING2 = 'Cord    '           / trailing blank test 2                          
END
```

And this is how the image is displayed in the gimp for example:

[image: fits file example]

So by the header I can understand the that each array item will have a 16 bits integer. The `BZERO` with this value means it's meant to be and unsigned integer of 16 bits. So far no problem. From the image generation I assumed that that each array item would represent a pixel and each value would be a representation of a color in the grayscale. 
The code bellow that is inside the ccfits library, generates numbers that goes from 0 to a max of 498 which is really far from the edge of a 16 bits integer. That being said, how does this goes from black to white? How this numbers are being scaled or transformed to represent a pixel and color?

Comment: Can you share the file?

Comment: Not knowing anything about the file-format, and only judging and guessing by the header and the attached image, it seems to be a *15*-bit (with the 16:th bit ignored) grayscale image, with values ranging from `0` to `32767`. One of the values (probably `0`) is black, and the other is white.

Comment: @MarkSetchell here: http://www.filedropper.com/atestfil

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I thought the same way. The image has 300x200 pxs and by the code I posted which generates the values it goes only until 498 (which is really far from 32767, which would be white). How does the other viewers are showing this as white?

Comment: Reading [the Wikipedia article about FITS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FITS) it seems like FITS files could be quite complex. So what is your purpose with these file? What are you going to use them for? Perhaps you should consider using a library instead of implementing it yourself?

Comment: **ImageMagick** shows the image as more or less black, as you would expect, and that the maximum value is 498, mean is 294 and min almost zero. I note that 300x200pixels at 16bits makes 60,000 pixels therefore 120,000 bytes, yet the file is 515,520 bytes...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am using a library to read it... but I have to convert the image data from fits to another one, hence my question...

Comment: @MarkSetchell a fits file consists of one or many headers and each header contains primary header that has some metadata in ASCII and a data array data is usually the image. This one I provided has 2 headers. Thats the reason it has more bigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FITS expert here, but I don't really understand your question.  First of all, the code you posted here isn't complete--there's a variable `row` that isn't defined clearly.  It's not at all clear the intent, but I guess it's filling a 300x200 array with some gradient.  FITS arrays are just that--arrays. N-dimensional arrays of some values of some data type.

How those values are intended to be interpreted is *completely* application specific, though there are viewers specifically designed for astronomical images such as the venerable [ds9](http://ds9.si.edu/site/Home.html) or the more modern [Glue](http://docs.glueviz.org/en/stable/index.html).

You wrote that you just opened the file in GIMP (I'm actually rather impressed that it can read FITS files).  All GIMP is doing, it looks like, for lack of a better option is linearly scaling the values in the array between black (probably starting at 0) and white.

Comment: It seems the case, but is there a pattern for this scaling? Because ds9, qfitsview and gimp are doing the same thing... What I don't understand is how it interprets it... How from 0 to ~500 becomes 0 to ~65k

Comment: It doesn't. The 16-bit data type you're using just means each pixel can have a value anywhere in a 16-bit signed range (more on that in a sec). But the image viewers are just scaling the actual values to some range of (possibly 8-bit) greyscale values. That's just a question of the image viewers on question though and nothing specific to FITS. Incidentally FITS doesn't have a native data type for unsigned integers, but the BZERO keyword means "add 32768 to every value", so they effectively become unsigned ints. This isn't really relevant to the question, just a curiosity.

Comment: If your question is just how the linear scaling works, if m=0 is the lowest value in the array and M=498 is the max value in the array, to scale a pixel's value x  to an 8-bit value, for example, you might do something like `round(x / float(M)) * 0xFF)`

Comment: Also, maybe you're asking "why use 16 bits per pixel" or something? I don't know what your interest is in FITS but keep in mind it was originally designed for astronomical instruments. So the question is what actually does the "value" of a pixel mean? For a CCD instrument this often means an actual photon count of each pixel during an exposure, where an assumption might be that 16-bits is enough to hold that count for a typical exposure time (ofc one could produce overexposure). You would then convert the photon count to some brightness value depending on the context.

Comment: Yeah. I understood that... my question was more related to what this viewers are doing, because I couldn't find anything related to that matter on the specification and the format simply does not care of what this data should represent in reality. It seems the viewers are adopting the same pattern in that matter. Your answer is not what I expected but I'll accept it anyways for showing at least an explanation of that viewers are doing under the hood.

Comment: I mean I don't know exactly for sure, but it's probably something like that.  Like I said the FITS specification doesn't make too many specifications as to how some arbitrary array is to be interpreted--it's intended to be very general.  There are specialized specifications for specific formats for specific instruments, however, though most generic viewers won't aprori know about them.